# URL Rewrite in htaccess not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a url [www.example.com/mybooks/list.php?id=novel-15](http://www.example.com/mybooks/list.php?id=novel-15) now i want to rewrite this url as  [www.example.com/mybooks/novel-15](http://www.example.com/mybooks/novel-15) for this i have the following code in .htaccess file

```
<Files ~ "\.log$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^mybooks/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ mybooks/list.php?id=?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

but this is not working. anybody give me a good solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in your `/mybooks/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mybooks/ 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /list\.php\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ list.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: my .htaccess file is in mybooks folder, and i tried mybooks/list.php?id=novel-15 url it wont re write as mybooks/novel-15

Comment: thax thalaivaa.... its working great. can u please explain it bcoz... i want to do something more tooo.... i want to rewrite mybooks/index.php?search_word=book&search_option=all  to mybooks/book

Comment: First redirect rule uses `THE_REQUEST`. `THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`. You can see very good examples and tutorial on askapache.com

Comment: i want to rewrite mybooks/index.php?search_word=book&search_option=all  to mybooks/book

Comment: Pls don't start a new question from comments. And that's not doable either since it can be either `list.php` or `index.php` but not both.